# Exponential of sum of number operator with ladder operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I'm considering a bosonic field mode with the the usual commutation relations for the creation and annihilation operators $\hat{a}, \hat{a}^\dagger$.

I'm looking to simplify a conjugation (transforming to the interaction picture), $e^{iH_0t/\hbar } \hat{X} e^{-iH_0t/\hbar }.$

I'm stuck trying to evaluate this term
$$ e^{i \left(c_1 \hat{N} + c_2 \left(\hat{a}  + \hat{a}^\dagger\right)\right)} \left(\hat{a} +\hat{a}^\dagger\right)e^{-i\left( c_1 \hat{N} + c_2 \left(\hat{a}  + \hat{a}^\dagger\right)\right)}.$$

First, I tried checking if the term in the exponential is a nice case where I can use a BCH type formula. Checking the commutators conditions:

$$ [\hat{N},\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger ]= \hat{a}^\dagger - \hat{a}, \,\, [\hat{N},\hat{a}^\dagger - \hat{a}]= \hat{a}^\dagger + \hat{a}.$$
So no commutator of the type $[X,[X,Y]]=[Y,[X,Y]]=0$ is satisfied.

Next, I tried to spot a pattern that may help me explicitly expand the exponential, but I'm not quite sure where its headed.

$$ \left(c_1 \hat{N}  + c_2 \left( \hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger \right)\right)^{k}\left( \hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger\right)= \left(c_1 \hat{N}  + c_2 \left( \hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger \right)\right)^{k-1}\left( c_1 \hat{N}(\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger) + c_2(\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger)^2 \right)$$
$$ =\left(c_1 \hat{N}  + c_2 \left( \hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger \right)\right)^{k-1}\left( c_1 \hat{N}(\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger) + c_2(\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger)^2 \right).$$

Then use the commutation relations above to simplify this and hopefuly simplify the series form of the exponenital, but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $e^{A}Be^{-A}=e^{[A,\cdot]}B$.

Comment: In case the notation @Qmechanic mentions is unfamiliar to you, OP, this means $B+\frac{1}{2!}[A,B]+\frac{1}{3!}[A,[A,B]]+\dots$, which is indeed the exponential of $[A,\cdot]$ applied to $B$. To prove this try to find the Taylor expansion around $x=0$ of $f(x)=e^{xA}Be^{-xA}$.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks for the hint, I solved it using that and finding a pattern in the iterated commutator.